# mysqli bind param number of variables error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get an error and i cant find out why it is giving me this error. I have been looking at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php and for all i can find out is the code that i am using correct. I received this code from an post on SO. Here is the code in question.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

$id=$_GET['id'];
if($data = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT * FROM cypg8_overzicht WHERE id="?"'))
{

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($data, "s", $id);

mysqli_stmt_execute($data); 
$data2 = mysqli_stmt_fetch($data);
}
```

And the error that I am receiving is as follows:

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in line 33. Line 33:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($data, "s", $id);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1** <== Error is gone
As suggested by Your Common Sence i needed to delete the quotes in the WHERE section. I did and now the error is gone. Jippiejay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not quote your placeholders

```
'SELECT * FROM cypg8_overzicht WHERE id=?'
```

Comment: Thank you that solves the error part. I am so sorry but my question was not complete. Could you please help me with the part under Edit 1.

Comment: `*sigh*`... why don't you get yourself some tutorial on getting data from prepared statement?

Comment: You mean like this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php I am going to look further but i dont understand everything. Please don't get me wrong i have been looking for hours to solve this problem in a matter effect it was yesterday 2 o clock in the night that i stopped and from this morning around 10 until now i am still looking to get this to work. I have tried all kinds of methods and can't get it to work. So i was hoping that some brilliant mind on SO would push me in the right direction or give the solution. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: And... you know, If you still have all your zillion PC1000s in this table - you're indeed in trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the help that I received from you. I do hope that we can stop bickering about a certain setup from a database.

Comment: This remark of mine was not on your database design in general but on the very problem of getting your data from db you have at the moment. Just an immediate consequence of the design.